# not getting the variable data in output

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I've been having a problem regarding the displaying of data from a variable in emu8086.
I display the String using the following code:

```
.model small
.data
v db 13, 'how are you doing','$'
.code
main proc

mov dx,OFFSET v
mov ah,09h  
int 21h

end main
main endp
```

but when I did it for numbers(1,2,3...) , it gives me the wrong output. let's say I have the 5 number stored in a variable, the value goes into the register is CD. I don't get it why the wrong value goes into the register

Following is the code:

```
.model small
.data
v db 5
.code
main proc
mov dl,v
mov ah,2  
int 21h

end main
main endp
```

A little help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

Here the screenshot of the problem: [Click here](https://github.com/uzairkabeer1/Screenshots/blob/main/assembly/p1.png)

Comment: It should not be `CD`, but int21/2 prints characters by ascii code so you would not get `5` anyway. Not sure about `.model small` requiring `ds` to be set up, but if it worked for the first example, you probably do not need that. Try `v db '5'` or `v db 0x35` and see what happens.

Comment: @Jester  yeah but I'm trying to perform arithmetic operations by using the number stored in variables, how can I do that then? I also tried the `v db 0x35`   still the CD hex stored in the register and the outputted value is `=`

Comment: Maybe emu8086 is using `mov dl,v` as address, so try `mov dl, [v]` instead.

Comment: @Jester I try `v db 0` after moving it into register `mov dl,v` or `mov dl,[v]` it gives the same answer `=` and CD is stored in the dl, i still don't get it how is this happening?

Comment: Then you might need to set `ds` up after all. Try `mov ax, @data; mov ds, ax` before the load.

Comment: the answer is still the same

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing relevant things?

Comment: `mov dl, '5'` should work, putting the ASCII code (0x35) for the digit `5` into DL.  You can single-step that with a debugger and verify you're seeing the right things.  Then you can then sort out your bugs with access to `.data` memory if you want; I'm pretty sure EMU8086 uses MASM-style syntax, so `mov dl, x` should load a byte from that address.

Comment: @Jester I've added the screenshot

Comment: @PeterCordes I've tried also your approach in code it still didn't work

Comment: Thank you. Can you uncover the register window so we can see `ds` as well? Also scroll up the disassembly and hex bytes to the `mov dx, offset v1` so we can see the address of `v1` for comparison. Look in memory at address `ds:0` and verify initial value is 5 and unchanged during single stepping.

Comment: Okay just give me a minute

Comment: @Jester [here the disassembly](https://github.com/uzairkabeer1/Screenshots/blob/main/assembly/p1a.png)

Comment: Hmm all of those look fine. `v1` is at address `0001` and `v` is at address `0000`. `DS` seems to be set properly since the message prints fine.  Can you dump memory at `0700:0000`? Check if the `5` is there and whether something overwrites it.

Comment: @Jester I've dumped the memory and found out that 5 is never there after the `mov dl,v` has called, the hex `CD` goes into the dl, not the address of v `0000`.

Comment: But is it there at the start of the program? What step overwrites it?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/uzairkabeer1/Screenshots/blob/main/assembly/p1b.png) the screenshot. I can't properly identify which step. As far it seems that the error arises on the value passing. but the thing is v is 0000 and the memory address can be seen in the SS. So, it must not cause an error.

Comment: I have tested, you **need** the `mov ax, @data; mov ds, ax`. Then it works fine. `DS` will probably be `0710`.